Is it possible to ask a postdoc from external university to guide my first undergraduate research?
I am a freshmen student from non top tier HK university and very interested in ML/AI/DL/RL/optimization, or some interesting applications of AI like AI for drug discovery. I have some skills:

school ICPC steam

linear algebra, Multi-variable calculus (self study), convex optimization(self study), discrete math (self study), probability with basic understanding in measure theory (self study), real & complex analysis (current self-studying), functional analysis (future)

Just started to play Kaggle, with not a bad understanding on ML


There are few problems:

My GPA is low, with 3.37/4.3 (ranking unknown, but probably top 15%)

Very few professors are working on the fields I'm interested in


Thus, I pretty sure professors from my school won't need me; I got no email response. Is it is possible to embark my undergraduate research for free/no price?
If you were a ML/AI postdoc at top university, are you willing to remotely supervise this undergraduate?

My two cents: particularly at the beginning basically every undergraduate needs significant hand holding. That really doesn't work well remotely.

First, I think it's great that you want to go further in your academic work. It sounds like you're intelligent and hardworking, which are important attributes to be successful.
I'm going to start by answering your main question, then I'll give you some suggestions that hopefully will be useful to your goals.
If you were a ML/AI postdoc at top university, are you willing to remotely supervise any undergraduate？
It's very unlikely that a postdoc at a top university would be interested in remotely supervising an undergrad at another university.
The reasons for this are that postdocs tend to be extremely busy, poorly paid, and hyperfocused on their own research.
Now, a tenured professor with more time (or the need to carry out some kind of outreach work) might be a more likely candidate in terms of time and disposition, but the problem here is that professors at top universities have no shortage of undergraduates at their own schools.
What Should You Do Instead
I'm going to give you some suggestions here that will improve the likelihood of hitting your goals. Because again, you clearly have the drive and motivation, now you just need to work on some logistics.
1. Improve your spelling and grammar in formal situations.
Your writing style is excessively casual for someone reaching out about a potential research partnership. If I were a professor interested in remote mentoring, and I saw this question with statements like:

cuz i got no email response

I would not be inclined to reach out to you with an offer.
Note that this is different than how I feel about someone trying to write formally, but who is making the types of grammar and spelling mistakes common for those for whom English isn't their first language.
Most people will overlook the latter to some degree, but will frown at excessive casualness in formal communication.
2. Focus on Making Yourself Competitive for Graduate School
If you are interested in embarking on graduate-level research, you need to think now about how you can make yourself a competitive candidate for grad school.
This is going to mean improving your GPA, your writing skills, and thinking ahead to what kinds of programs you might wish to apply to.
3. Dig Deeper or Consider Transferring
If you are set on ML drug discovery undergraduate research, I suggest spending more time talking to professors at your current university about options. They are much more likely to help you than a remote professor or postdoc.
If nobody at your university is doing undergraduate research that you're interested in, consider transferring to a different undergrad program.
But I would make transferring a last resort and instead:
4. Recognize What Actually Matters To Future Grad Schools
Even if you can't find someone at your school doing ML-based drug discovery, doing any kind of mentored undergraduate research project is going to be a benefit when you later apply to grad school.
Grad school admissions committees typically aren't looking at undergraduate applications and thinking things like, "We need to find the best experts in ML-drug discovery in this set of applications..."
They are thinking, "We need to find people that have shown they can be successful in the high-stress academic environment of grad school."
For better or worse, that's going to include (depending on the school) metrics such as:

Communications skills as shown in your essays and other communications
Experience doing mentored research (any mentored research)
GPA
GRE scores (for US universities)
Leadership and volunteer experience
Letters of recommendation from professors

So, by all means continue working on Kaggle competitions if you find those interesting. But if you are serious about entering the world of mentored research, consider the suggestions above.

Thanks for your very helpful suggestions!
